# Fatal error: Call to a member function setEmailValue() on boolean in

Tags: magento2, email

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setEmailValue() on boolean in 
>   /home/babyesse/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
>   on line 703

hi am getting this error when the customer are trying to reset their password in magento ver Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

basically it will not event redirect them to the reset account form... 
below is the line 703 in the AccountController.php

i followed the error path and can't figure out what is wrong there

```
public function forgotPasswordAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('forgotPassword')->setEmailValue(
        $this->_getSession()->getForgottenEmail()
    );
    $this->_getSession()->unsForgottenEmail();

    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

i am new to magento please help how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your customer.xml file for "customer_account_forgotpassword".

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
        <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
            <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

Comment: appears i have a few of those which one has to be updated ?


/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customer.xml
/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme690/layout/customer.xml
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml

Comment: the file in the theme you are having issue.[default/base/rwd]

Comment: by the any solution you found???

Answer (score 0):

File: app/design/frontend/Project/theme-name/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_forgotpassword.xml
I just renamed `name="forgotPassword"` to `name="forgotPasswords"` and it worked:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Forgotpassword" name="forgotPasswords" template="Magento_Customer::form/forgotpassword.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```